# How to return percentage in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage, postgresql-9.3

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE percentage(
  gid SERIAL,
  zoom smallint NOT NULL,
  x smallint NOT NULL,
  y smallint NOT NULL
);
```

INSERT DATA

```
INSERT INTO percentage(zoom, x, y) VALUES
(0,5,20), 
(0,5,21), (0,5,21),
(0,5,22), (0,5,22), (0,5,22),
(0,5,23), (0,5,23), (0,5,23), (0,5,23),
(0,5,24), (0,5,24), (0,5,24), (0,5,24), (0,5,24),
(1,5,20), 
(1,5,21), (1,5,21),
(1,5,22), (1,5,22), (1,5,22),
(1,5,23), (1,5,23), (1,5,23), (1,5,23),
(1,5,24), (1,5,24), (1,5,24), (1,5,24), (1,5,24);
```

How many times certain tile shows up (**tile** is represented by **x and y**)

```
SELECT zoom, x, y, count(*) AS amount 
FROM percentage 
GROUP BY zoom,x,y 
ORDER BY zoom, amount;
```

Result:

```
 zoom | x | y  | amount 
------+---+----+--------
    0 | 5 | 20 |      1
    0 | 5 | 21 |      2
    0 | 5 | 22 |      3
    0 | 5 | 23 |      4
    0 | 5 | 24 |      5
    1 | 5 | 20 |      1
    1 | 5 | 21 |      2
    1 | 5 | 22 |      3
    1 | 5 | 23 |      4
    1 | 5 | 24 |      5
(10 rows)
```

**Question**

How to get back percentage of each tile (x and y) for certain zoom, or in other words, how many times have the certain tile showed up for certain zoom?

Wanted result:

```
 zoom | x | y  | amount | percentage
------+---+----+--------+-----------
    0 | 5 | 20 |      1 |     6.667
    0 | 5 | 21 |      2 |    13.333
    0 | 5 | 22 |      3 |        20
    0 | 5 | 23 |      4 |    26.667
    0 | 5 | 24 |      5 |    33.333
    1 | 5 | 20 |      1 |     6.667
    1 | 5 | 21 |      2 |    13.333
    1 | 5 | 22 |      3 |        20
    1 | 5 | 23 |      4 |    26.667
    1 | 5 | 24 |      5 |    33.333
(10 rows)
```

*This is just a sample data, percentages are not supposed to be the same, except as a pure coincidence!

Comment: based on the sample data, should all percentages not be the same, as they occurred once per zoom?

Comment: @vkp data is just a sample, percentages are very likely not going to be the same for each zoom level!

Comment: What is the logic for that percentage those do not add up to **100** something is wrong

Comment: @Prdp You are very right, I have calculated it very much wrong! Sorry about that! I have corrected it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If am not wrong you are looking for this

```
SELECT zoom,x,y,
       amount,
       ( amount / Cast(Sum(amount) OVER(partition BY zoom) AS FLOAT) ) * 100 as amt_percentage
FROM   (SELECT zoom,x, y,
               Count(*) AS amount
        FROM   percentage
        GROUP  BY zoom,x,y) a
```

Or even

```
SELECT zoom,x,y,
       Count(*) AS amount,
       ( Count(*) / Cast(Sum(Count(*))OVER(partition BY zoom) AS FLOAT) ) * 100 AS amt_percentage
FROM   percentage
GROUP  BY zoom,x,y
```

*Casting* the denominator to `FLOAT` is avoid the `Integer` division